Why does this modified Newton's method fail to converge for N > 1 iterations?
I am investigating the behavior of an approximation of 1/sqrt(x) which uses a similar method to the more famous Quake III "Fast Inverse Square Root". Quake's FISR uses an approximation of the logarithm of a floating point number to supply a good initial guess to Newton's method (Newton-Raphson, here abbreviated NR). With a good y_n, an improved y_n+1 can be found by:

In code this is commonly expressed as (In 1949 D.H. Hartree showed you could skip a division step by doing so):

However, one of the advantages of using the FISR is you don't need to compute 2, 3, or 4 iterations of NR to get to a suitable result. With a good guess, one iteration is usually sufficient. With that in mind one could, as Jan Kadlec did in 2010, chose not just an optimal "magic" constant, but search potential replacements for the values 1.5 and 0.5 in the equation above to find parameters which might be optimal for one iteration only. Kadlec landed on:

This is indeed competitive with Quake's FISR, achieving a comparable error with one NR iteration.

Code to generate the above plot is here.
However, if instead we allow it to iterate to a given tolerance, the algorithm stalls, with only negligible changes to the output. This is evident at a tolerance of 0.001 and can be seen in C code you can run on replit.

Code for the above plot (and some other tests) is here. I have not run exhaustive tests, so I do not know if the approximation always stalls under the desired value but that appears to be the case.
This behavior does not change if the precision of the digits used is changed--values of 0.7 and 2.4 will produce roughly similar results. It is also not due to the "magic" constant, which can be replaced with e.g. 0x5f3759df and see the same result. If you change nothing about the code but the NR step, replacing it with y.f = y.f * (1.5f - 0.5f * x * y.f^2), the approximation converges. I have performed these tests but they are not in the code examples linked above, which I have tried to keep brief.
Clearly the problem is the modified NR step. What I want to know is:

Why does this approximation work well for one iteration and then "stall" indefinitely at a value pretty near but not quite the right result?

While an answer might be "that's not Newton's method, so that's why it doesn't work", that doesn't explain to me why it might perform so well on the first iteration.
It's been a long time since I've had a math class, so my apologies for not couching the above in more precise terms. I've tagged this as "floating-point" because that's the system we are working in, not because I think this problem arises from any of the vagaries of floating point arithmetic.

D.H. Hartree "Notes on iterative processes," Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, Vol. 45 , No. 2, April 1949, pp. 230 - 236, specifically pp. 233-234


One way I could narrow this question is to plot the behavior of the approx as the NR step is mutated from Kadlec's version to the original. I'll have to think about how do do that (hints/ideas appreciated)

If the function is tweaked to give you the best first approximation I would expect it to converge to that approximation rather than the actual value.

That may be true. There are others who use slightly modified NR parameters: Blinn 1997 uses 1.47 and 0.47; Kahan Ng 1986 use 1.5 - powf(2, -30); Moroz et. al 2019 use 1.50131454 and 0.500438180. Those are obviously much closer to 1.5 and 0.5, but what does the boundary look like? I don't know.

If the sequence
$$
y_{n+1} = Ay_n(B-xy_n^2),
$$
where $A$, $B$, $x\neq 0$ are some constants, converges to $1/\sqrt{x}$, then the following equality must be satisfied
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{x}} =\frac{A}{\sqrt{x}}\left(B-x\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2\right) \quad\Rightarrow\quad A(B-1) = 1
$$
For $A = 0.703952253$, $B = 2.38924456$ we have $A(B-1) = 0.977961838 \neq 1$, so we cannot expect convergence to $1/\sqrt{x}$ regardless of the initial guess, $y_0$, or the number of digits.

Thank you! I think this is it, though I'll wait to mark it as the answer for now.

Hmm. I think the sequence is y_n+1 = y_n * (A - B * x * y_n^2), so the constraint should be x!=0, B = A - 1

If you write the formula this way, then yes. I based my answer on the Kadlec formula.

Working off @gec's answer, I have verified that the modified NR procedure converges if the values are changed to meet the constraint and fails to converge if they are not changed.
The standard Newton-Raphson approximation is:
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{x}} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(A-Bx\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2\right)
$$
Then the constraint is B = A - 1, which is true for the standard choices of A = 1.5 and B = 0.5 as well as Blinn's A = 1.47, B = 0.47
If we approximate using Kadlec's modified form Gec reminds us our approximation is:
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{x}} =\frac{A}{\sqrt{x}}\left(B-x\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2\right)
$$
For this to be a good approximation, A(B-1) must equal 1.
I wanted to return to the code I used to see how this shakes out. If we choose A = 0.712 and B = 2.4045, we meet the constraints. In order to convince myself that worked and show how it might diverge, I wrote code to plot the different constant choices and how they behave as we move from not just violating the constraint vs. not but transitioning between the standard form, which has one constraint, and Kadlec's form which has another.
Modified to meet the constraint, both forms work well. With the constraint violated, the problem quickly appears.

Plotted on the same scale, the problem becomes apparent immediately. Even for a version which is only slightly different from the standard in form and constant selection, the approximation stalls immediately. Gec answered my question so that will stay the selected answer, but I thought that an answer in the visual context of the question might be useful to someone other than me.
